# Is there a need of a website(server) to handle gcm operations like uploading attachments,logins,etc

Tags: android, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

My team is developing a chat app using gcm xmpp.

We are a bit lost.What is the use of

`public static final String SERVER_URL = "my website name"`

`public static final String USER_REGISTER_URL="my website/register.php"`(also same for signin)

`public static final String SEND_MSG_URL ="website/message.php"`

Do we need a website to handle gcm messages(like attachments) and registrations
If yes how to get one

Or is there any other way out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Cloud Connect service is not an XMPP server that is fully exposed to the clients. It allows only communication between clients and your own service. The service could handle the messages and redispatch them the right user. It means that if you want to build a chat on top of that service, you need to have your own server components to do the actual message routing between users.

It also means that you will not have all the power of XMPP available but only basic messaging. As such it is not a full alternative to using a full XMPP server.

Comment: So sir for data transfer,upload,registration,sqlite all operations can i buy a domain like for example(.com) www.mydomain.com and use it as a server  to manage all the operations and use it in server_url=www.mydomain.com

Comment: It is not just about buying a domain. It is much about developing the server component.

Comment: sir, http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.0.2    what is the use of theses packages,i know i have to use them in my apache->http->annotation,auth,client etc and code them

Comment: There is many approach to do it. It depends on the programming language you want to use, etc. Documentation by Google explaining how to implement GCM Connection Server upstream messaging is available here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs#upstream You can find a tutorial for one possible approach here: http://javapapers.com/android/android-chat-with-google-gcm-xmpp/

Comment: Sir basically can i buy a domain of some hosting like godaddy and use that website as a server and program it to interact with gcm so that i dont need a pc which acts as a server and keep it online all the time?

Comment: No, first you need to develop your server code to make it sure it works as you want before you buy anything.